# Why Navigation throws null exception when returning to a page 2nd time

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, nullreferenceexception, dispatcher

I have a serial port controller (for sensing any object that passes through its transport module) connected to USB. It responses with either *0* or *1* after input command `t` when it senses any dropping or no dropping of object through the transport. The page `CshDeposit5` contains the code. `Start.xaml` is the page the activity starts and ends up in `CshDeposit5.xaml` as follows:

`Start.xaml`->`Lang`->`Menu`->`CshDeposit5.xaml`->`TmpMsg.xaml` or `TmpErrorMsg.xaml`->`Start.xaml`

`TmpErrorMsg` and `TmpMsg` are the pages to show the user what happened. Everything runs fine for the first time. But when it tries to come to this `CshDeposit5.xaml` 2nd time it throws exception on the following codes:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate
{
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("TmpMsg.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
}));
```

Comment: `NullReferenceexception` on what? It would be good to add exception message to your question. In any case some of your variables doesn't contains a class instance, but `null` instead. For example `NavigationService`. If it's not a class instance but `null`, it doesn't have the method `Navigate`. Why it's `null` instead of class instance on second pass you have to debug.

Comment: I used the Debugger and found _noparentpage=-1 when the navigationservice is called the 2nd time but can't figure put why?

Comment: At the breakpoint on navigationservice for the 1st time it shows the following:
CanGoBack: true
CanGoForward: false
Content: {NWCDM.CshDeposit5}
CurrentSource: {CshDeposit5.xaml}
Source: {CshDeposit5.xaml}

And for the 2nd entry on navigatioservice:

NavigationService: null
_noParentPage: -1